# Photoresistor Night Switch

Tags: switches, ldr, operational-amplifier

I have a problem regarding the schematic from the link below.

I made the schematic from this link, at figure 5:http://www.nutsvolts.com/magazine/article/light-sensitive-circuits

The problem is that when the light descreases there is a level of light when the relay is turning ON and OFF at a very high speed. 
I tried to repair this by increasing the 1M resistor to 4.7M, but it does not solve the problem. 
I saw that there is an operational amplifier with positive feedback (hysterezis), so I tought that modifying the value of 1M resistor could solve the problem by modifying the value at which the AO is turning ON.

What can be done to eliminate the fast switching between ON and OFF of the relay ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says on the linked page, "The magnitude of hysteresis is inversely proportional to the R5 value, being zero when R5 is open circuit."  So if you need more hysteresis to reduce the chattering of the output, you should *decrease* the value of R5.

You may be fighting against external feedback:  The light illuminates the sensor when on.  If there's enough of that, it's hard to get the circuit to work.  So you might benefit from making sure very little of the controlled light falls on the sensor.